# making a dropdown menu from react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-bootstrap

I am trying to map my state which contains several words to a react-bootstrap dropdown menu below I have included my attempt

my state looks like "some words to view" with each word separated by a space

I have tried mapping the items into a 'ul' element using a for loop but The dropdown doesn't show anything at all.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import {Button,InputGroup,Dropdown,DropdownButton,ButtonGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class BreakPointsDropdown extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render(props){
    return (
    <Dropdown as={ButtonGroup}>
    <Button variant="outline-dark"onClick={this.props.addBreakPointMode}>Add Breakpoint</Button>

    <Dropdown.Toggle split variant="outline-dark" id="dropdown-split-basic" />

    <Dropdown.Menu id="menulist" onClick={()=>{
      var list = this.props.listOfBreakPoints.split(" ")
      var ul = document.createElement("ul")

        for(let i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
          let li = document.createElement("li")
          li.innerHTML= list[i]
          ul.append(li)
        }
        document.getElementById("menulist").append(ul)
    }}>

    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>

    );
  }

};
```

I would like the dropdown menu to contain a list of words from my state which I can select onclick

Comment: What is the dropdown component from? You most likely shouldn't be manually manipulating DOM.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure exactly how to answer. I am rendering the dropdown menu as its own component I will update the code to show this.

Comment: I think by your statement you mean: use a prop as the content instead of generating it onClick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid modifying the dom directly...unless it's really required. Your component can be easily rewritten as

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {Button,Dropdown,ButtonGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class BreakPointsDropdown extends Component{
  handleSelect = (value) => {
    alert(value);
    // Do something with the value
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <Dropdown as={ButtonGroup}>
    <Button variant="outline-dark"onClick={this.props.addBreakPointMode}>Add Breakpoint</Button>

    <Dropdown.Toggle split variant="outline-dark" id="dropdown-split-basic" />

    <Dropdown.Menu id="menulist">
        {this.props.listOfBreakPoints.split(" ").map(eachBreakpoint => {
            return (
              <Dropdown.Item
                onClick={() => this.handleSelect(eachBreakpoint)}
                key={eachBreakpoint}
              >
                {eachBreakpoint}
              </Dropdown.Item>
            );
        })}
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>

);
  }
};
```

And rendered with

```
<BreakPointsDropdown listOfBreakPoints="Hi Hello How are you"/>
```

A sample playground: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-msdpvz

Coming back to the question..

*"*I have tried mapping the items into a 'ul' element using a for loop but The dropdown doesn't show anything at all.*"*

**Because your entire code is inside an onclick handler.** Your code runs when you click on the empty dropdown section that you get on clicking the dropdown arrow.

```
<Dropdown.Menu id="menulist" onClick={()=>{
      var list = this.props.listOfBreakPoints.split(" ")
      var ul = document.createElement("ul")

        for(let i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
          let li = document.createElement("li")
          li.innerHTML= list[i]
          ul.append(li)
        }
        document.getElementById("menulist").append(ul)
    }}>
```

Try it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ruat5w

Click on dropdown arrow -> You should see an empty div -> Click on the empty div to see your dom modification code getting executed.

Comment: thanks for the description and very verbose explanation! this solution worked for me.